# How to access the variable defined under nested anonymous namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am writing some toy programs to try out the functionality of various C++ keywords. I've declared an anonymous namespace nested under another anonymous namespace and both the namespaces (nester and nested) define a variable `i` as under:

```
namespace {
    int i = 80;
    namespace {
        int i = 90;
    }
}
```

I can access the variable `i` defined under top level namespace  using `::i`, but how can I access the variable `i` defined under the nested namespace?

Comment: *anonymous namepaces* are (typically) implicitly *`inlined`*. outside those namespace scope, you'll have two of such names `i` visible within the *translation unit* - you will not even be able to use the name `i` without a *qualified name-lookup*. Unfortunately you do not know the unique *name* of the namespace the inner `i` belongs to. So, You can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the variable in the inner scope a unique name you can access it outside the anonymous namespaces but so long as the name collision exists you are only going to be able to access it by name from the innermost namespace. You could access it some other way (create a reference in the innermost namespace for example, or a function)

Comment: you mean it's not feasible?